# Parallel.For looping on the same value

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing

I'm trying to make a simple parallel.For and It seems to be getting the same "i" over and over again.
My code is:

```
String[] str = new String[10000];

Parallel.For(0,10000, i=>

{

if(str[i] == string.Empty)

   str[i] = "ok";

else

   str[i] = "SameValue";

});
```

I would expect it to never get to "else"

Comment: I see two problems with this code.  It is ugly as sin.  Your `If` statement also always returns false.  Unless Parallel.For increases the value of `i` that might explain the reason its not changing.  Your question is confusing not entirely sure what you mean by "the same i over and over again"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string.Empty` does not equal `null`, change your if condition to

`if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str[i]))`

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect it to never get to "else"

Wrong - the string array elements are initialized with `null` (their default value as reference type) - not `string.Empty`. Hence *only* the `else` part is ever executed.

You can easily verify this yourself by setting a break point on the `if` statement.